# Including SOIL2 library in a CMake project

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, soil

I'm trying to include SOIL2 in my C++ OpenGL project.

So far I've

- downloaded the library from https://github.com/SpartanJ/SOIL2
- built it by running premake 4 and make.
- copied the src/SOIL2/ directory to /usr/local/include
- tried adding libsoil2-debug.a to /usr/local/lib
- followed various examples of ways to include libraries with CMake

Platform is MacOS (Catalina)
I'm still new to CMake, so I'm pretty sure that's where my problem is.

At the moment, my CMakeLists file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(This ComputerGraphicsProgramming)
project(${This} CXX C)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOIL2_SOURCES /usr/local/include/SOIL2/*.c)
add_executable(${This} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

include_directories(
  include
  lib
  /usr/local/include
)
link_directories(
  /usr/local/include
  /usr/local/include/SOIL2
)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(glew REQUIRED)
find_package(glm REQUIRED)
find_library(soil2-debug REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${This}
  GLEW::GLEW
  ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} glfw
  soil2-debug
)
```

Texture.hpp, the file where I'm including SOIL, looks like this:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SOIL2/SOIL2.h>
#include <string>

class Texture
{
  public:
    Texture(std::string filename);
    ~Texture();

  private:
    unsigned int m_ID;
};
```

And these are my errors when I run make:

```sh
$ make
[  9%] Linking CXX executable ComputerGraphicsProgramming
ld: library not found for -lsoil2-debug
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [ComputerGraphicsProgramming] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ComputerGraphicsProgramming.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try copying it to /usr/lib instead?

Comment: I've tried putting libsoil2-debug.a in /usr/local/lib and adding /usr/local/lib via include_directories and link_directories.
Copying / linking to /usr/lib gives me permission errors, even if I run with sudo

Answer (score 2):

Finally got project to build, using the following CMakeLists file. Thanks for the replies!

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(This ComputerGraphicsProgramming)

project(${This} CXX C)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES src/*.cpp)
add_executable(${This} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

include_directories(
  include
  /usr/local/include
)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(glew REQUIRED)
find_package(glm REQUIRED)
find_library(SOIL2 soil2-debug)

target_link_libraries(${This}
  GLEW::GLEW
  ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} glfw
  ${SOIL2}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like the libsoil2-debug.a couldn't be found. Try to add /usr/local/lib into your [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html):

`list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/lib")`

somewhere on the top of your CMakeList.txt file

Comment: Turned out I was just using find_library wrong, but this got me on the right track, so many thanks!